# Keep converted (with .ToString()) datetime converted

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TextBox where there is a date. I convert the date with the following line of code:

```
txtTextbox.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTextbox.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The text in the textbox is now "05/12/1978".

But when I click inside the textbox to edit the date but I change my mind and I leave the textbox, the text is as follows: "05/12/1978 0:00:00".

I tried to fix this by converting the date in the `txtTextbox_Leave` event but that doesn’t work.

EDIT:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TableAdapters
        tblWerknemersTA = new dtsGIPTableAdapters.tblWerknemersTableAdapter();
        tblAfdelingenTA = new dtsGIPTableAdapters.tblAfdelingenTableAdapter();

        // DataSet
        dtsGIP = new dtsGIP();
        tblWerknemersTA.Fill(dtsGIP.tblWerknemers);
        tblAfdelingenTA.Fill(dtsGIP.tblAfdelingen);

        // DataView
        dtvWerknemers = dtsGIP.tblWerknemers.DefaultView;
        dtvWerknemers.Sort = "Familienaam ASC";

        // BindingSource
        tblWerknemersBS = new BindingSource();
        tblWerknemersBS.DataMember = "tblWerknemers";
        tblWerknemersBS.DataSource = dtvWerknemers;

        // Databindings
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", tblWerknemersBS, "Geboortedatum"));

        // Convert date
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
```

In this demo app I have two Textboxes, the problem occurs when I click on the first one and then on the second one.

EDIT 2:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TableAdapters
        tblWerknemersTA = new dtsGIPTableAdapters.tblWerknemersTableAdapter();
        tblAfdelingenTA = new dtsGIPTableAdapters.tblAfdelingenTableAdapter();

        // DataSet
        dtsGIP = new dtsGIP();
        tblWerknemersTA.Fill(dtsGIP.tblWerknemers);
        tblAfdelingenTA.Fill(dtsGIP.tblAfdelingen);

        // DataView
        dtvWerknemers = dtsGIP.tblWerknemers.DefaultView;
        dtvWerknemers.Sort = "Familienaam ASC";

        // BindingSource
        tblWerknemersBS = new BindingSource();
        tblWerknemersBS.DataMember = "tblWerknemers";
        tblWerknemersBS.DataSource = dtvWerknemers;

        // Databindings
        Binding textBoxBinding = new Binding("text", tblWerknemersBS, "Geboortedatum");
        textBoxBinding.FormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(textBoxBinding);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using windows forms or WPF?

Comment: I’m using WinForms

Comment: You should tag the question accordingly. I have done this for you this time.

Comment: This looks very much like you are using databinding. Are you? It is important to include this kind of information in your question, preferrably with some compilable code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], since the text does not change on its own

Comment: Wherever you bind the datetime - use `.ToShortDateString()` and the force will be with you

Comment: @Fabjan That's assuming the OP is running on a culture with that specific date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use data binding, it will update the control when the data changes. Unless you specify a specific format, it will use the default format for that. Setting the bound property to a specific value as you do is rather unusual, since you usually let the bound data determine the displayed value. In any case, you can not rely on a specific format that you use when you set the value (unless it matches the binding format).

The solution in your case is to set the binding format:

```
// Databindings
Binding textBoxBinding = new Binding("text", tblWerknemersBS, "Geboortedatum", true,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "d");
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(textBoxBinding);
```

Comment: It doesn't use the FormatString for some reason. The text in the textbox is "5/12/1978 0:00:00" and not "05/12/1978". Am I missing something? Check my questing for the complete code.

Comment: Did you define another binding somewhere else (e.g. in the visual designer)?

Comment: No I did not. This is a test project with two textboxes and the database.

Comment: Check the auto-generated code and compare it with your code. That will most likely point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have incorporated the changes in the original code.